# General Solution to a Differential Equation containing both x and y?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution of the differential equation:
>   $$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-9\frac{dy}{dx}+20y=60x+13$$

I found this interesting question, I've never had a problem with solving differential equations with $y$'s but I have no idea how this is done when there is an $x$ involved too? Do I integrate both sides? I would kindly appreciate any hints or ideas. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-9\frac{dy}{dx}+20y=60x+13$$

Then the auxilliary equation (which arises by letting $y=e^{\lambda x}$): $$\lambda^2 -9\lambda+20=0\implies (\lambda-4)(\lambda-5)=0\implies \lambda =4\quad\text{or}\quad\lambda=5$$

Then the complementary function:

$$y_{CF}=c_1e^{4x}+c_2e^{5x}$$

Now we try a particular integral $y_{PI} = ax+b$

Then $y'=a,\quad y''=0$. Substituting this in:

$$0-9a+20(ax+b)=60x+13$$

$20b-9a = 13$

$20a = 60\implies a=3$

Then $20b=27+13=40\implies b=2$

Then our general solution is given by:$$y_{GS} =y_{CF}+y_{PI} =c_1e^{4x}+c_2e^{5x}+3x+2$$

Note you can check the answer is correct by differentiating it twice, then substituting back into the original equation to verify that LHS=RHS

Comment: This is extremely useful, I get most of this solution apart from this tiny bit "y″=0 "

Comment: @NatD We have that $y_{PI}=ax+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants, so then $y'=\frac{dy}{dx} = a$ and $y''=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(a)=0$ since $a$ is a constant.

Comment: I got it now, can I use this approach if I have x^2 on the RHS? 13x^2 + 17 for example?

Comment: @NatD Then you would try a particular integral $y_{PI} = ax^2+bx+c$, and then sub in to find the coefficients. Note that you can derive these particular integrals instead of guessing, but I get the impression that might be slightly out of your reach at this stage. Here is a link to some standard ones which you can remember (look at page 2 table 1)http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap19/19_6.pdf

Comment: This makes so much sense now and I am currently looking into your link, thank you for the file I am finding the examples in there useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a second order linear non-homogeneous ODE.
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+p(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+q(x)y=r(x)$$
One may use [Variation of Parameters](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx). An advantage to this method in contrary to the [Method of Undetermined Coefficients](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx) is that we **do not** have to **guess** the form of the particular solution.

We must first find the complementary solution $y_c(x)$. This is done by setting $r(x)=0$. For our case, this is:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-9\frac{dy}{dx}+20y=0$$
This can be solved using the ansatz $y=e^{\lambda x}$. The characteristic equation is thus:
$$\lambda^2-9\lambda+20=0 \implies \lambda=4,5$$
Hence, our complementary solution is:
$$y_c(x)=c_1 e^{4x}+c_2 e^{5x} \tag{1}$$

---

Let's now find the particular solution $y_p(x)$.

We have the basis solutions $e^{4x}$ and $e^{5x}$. Thus, our [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) is:
$$W(x)=\begin{vmatrix} e^{4x} & e^{5x} \\ \frac{d}{dx}(e^{4x}) & \frac{d}{dx}(e^{5x}) \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} e^{4x} & e^{5x} \\ 4e^{4x} & 5e^{5x} \end{vmatrix}=e^{9x}$$
Now, we have $r(x)=60x+13$. The particular solution is given by:
$$y_p(x)=v_1(x)e^{4x}+v_2(x)e^{5x} \tag{2}$$
Where:
$$v_1(x)=-\int \frac{r(x)\cdot e^{5x}}{W(x)}~dx=-\int e^{-4x}(60x+13)~dx$$
And:
$$v_2(x)=\int \frac{r(x)\cdot e^{4x}}{W(x)}~dx=\int e^{-5x}(60x+13)~dx$$
Can you continue? After evaluating these integrals and substituting into $(2)$, use the fact that:
$$y(x)=y_c(x)+y_p(x)$$
I strongly recommend you to look at some other problems using Variation of Parameters given by the [link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx) I gave above.

Comment: Okay, I can do the part (1) easily and I am looking into the part (2). I am also looking into the link you gave me, and hopefully by doing more examples I will get my head around this.